# Ellipses given focus and two points

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I would like to **find all ellipses which contain 2 given points and has one focus at origin (zero)**. All in 2D plane.

There are several possible approaches but I'm not sure which is the best - both looks quite difficult to solve algebraically.

1. using **polar equation relative to focus** with $(R_1,\phi_1),(R_2,\phi_2)$, being coordinates of points
   $$ R_1 = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-ecos(\phi_1-\theta)} $$
   $$ R_2 = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-ecos(\phi_2-\theta)} $$
   then for given $\theta$ solve for semimajor axis $a$ and eccentricity $e$
2. using deffinition of elipse as a **set of points of the same distance from both foci**. Given 2 points of cartesian coordinates $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ and one focus in origin $(0,0)$. For each given distance parameter $L$ solve for coordinates of second focus $(x_f,y_f)$,
   $$ L = \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_2^2} + \sqrt{(x_1 - x_f)^2 + (y_1 - y_f)^2} $$
   $$ L = \sqrt{x_2^2 + y_2^2} + \sqrt{(x_2 - x_f)^2 + (y_2 - y_f)^2} $$
3. I can also first rotate the coordinate system (or my input points) by given angle (which is my arbitrary parameter) and then use some simplified equation of **ellipse which has major axis parallel to x-axis** which has just 2 degrees of freedom. But even after this rotation I don't see much simplification of algebraic solution.

**Or is there any better way?**

---

The resulting equations are quite difficult to solve. I wonder if there is some trick to simplify it and make it more elegant.

Also, because I would later to implement it into computational code where it would be computed manytimes per second, I would prefer solution inf form which is fast to evaluate numerically ( prefferably without goniometric or any transcedental functions )

---

**Why I'm interested ?** - I need it for some optimalization of orbital transfers for spaceship orbiting the Sun. I asked also in physics.stackexchange, and people recomand me that I should rather go to math section.

Comment: This is quite an interesting problem.  Note that given points $P_1,P_2$, with a very few exceptions there are at least two non-trivially different ellipses that can be specified which satisfy every valid $L$ value.  I'm still working out the details to provide an answer for you.

Comment: Try plotting the problem in the complex plane.

Comment: @prokop-hapala Did you solve your problem? I am having the exact same problem but the answer given below doesn't really help me! Can you explain how you find such an ellipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a$ is the semi-major axis of one such ellipse, and $F$ its other focus, then
$$ |R_1|+|R_1-F|=2a=|R_2|+|R_2-F|. $$
Subtracting one from the other, $F$ must satisfy the following equation:
$$ |F-R_1|-|F-R_2|=|R_2|-|R_1|. $$
The set of all points $F$ that satisfy this equation is a [hyperbola](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperbola.html) with focuses $R_1$ and $R_2$, and the semi-major axis $-\frac12\big||R_1|-|R_2|\big|$, and it is easy to find coordinates of points on the hyperbola using standard formulas (see the mathworld link, e.g.).

Comment: Very nice answer, short and effective! ;-)